# How to make a linkTag from the specific Tag in a XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I want to change the specifics Tags in following XML. The tags *`<linkSource>`* should be convert to  `<fo:basic-link internal-destination="boothId">` and the tag  `<linkDestination>` should be convertet to `<fo:block id="boothId">`.

```
<root>
<directCompNotes>
  <paragraph>Go to:</paragraph>
  <bullet-list>
    <item>
      <paragraph>
        <linkSource>
          Booth
        </linkSource>
      </paragraph>
    </item>
    <item>
      <paragraph>
        WithoutLinkSource
      </paragraph>
    </item>
  </bullet-list>
</directCompNotes>
<directComp>
  <paragraph>
    <linkDestination>
      Explainition
    </linkDestination>
  </paragraph>
</directComp>
</root>
```

That is what I tried to do:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  
      <xsl:for-each select="directCompNotes/bullet-list/item/paragraph/linkSource">
        <fo:basic-link internal-destination="boothId">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:basic-link>
      </xsl:for-each>
    
  </xsl:template>
```

The goal is that I should be able to create a link from "Booth" to "Explanition". All of the linkSource and linkDestinition are in the XML file already defined.

Can anyone help me please?

(Sorry, My English is not very well, but I hope I was able to explain the question well).

Comment: I just want to create a pdf from this Xml file.. But i did not want to share all my xslt code here.

Comment: What I said was, why don't you just use Notepad++ and do a find / replace from one element name to the desired element name? That is what you have asked to do in the question. So why not use find / replace? Then you can just use your new XSL file for PDF work etc. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: Nice Idea! But It must be an automation that runs every day. And every Day could be a new xml file.. That is why, it should be run Dynamicly

Comment: Now I understand why you are doing it this way. Perhaps that should be in your question to give context.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <directCompNotes>
        <paragraph>Go to:</paragraph>
        <bullet-list>
            <item>
                <paragraph>
                    <linkSource>Booth</linkSource>
                </paragraph>
            </item>
            <item>
                <paragraph>WithoutLinkSource</paragraph>
            </item>
        </bullet-list>
    </directCompNotes>
    <directComp>
        <paragraph>
            <linkDestination>Explainition</linkDestination>
        </paragraph>
    </directComp>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="linkSource">
        <fo:basic-link internal-destination="boothId">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:basic-link>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="linkDestination">
        <fo:block id="boothId">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <directCompNotes>
    <paragraph>Go to:</paragraph>
    <bullet-list>
      <item>
        <paragraph>
          <fo:basic-link internal-destination="boothId">Booth</fo:basic-link>
        </paragraph>
      </item>
      <item>
        <paragraph>WithoutLinkSource</paragraph>
      </item>
    </bullet-list>
  </directCompNotes>
  <directComp>
    <paragraph>
      <fo:block id="boothId">Explainition</fo:block>
    </paragraph>
  </directComp>
</fo:root>
```